# Stupid Product Topology Question

Tags: general-topology

Please forgive me for asking such an easy question. I'm still getting used to the concept of product topologies. Problem: Find a non-empty topological space $X$ such that $X \cong X \times X$ (with product topology). So my thought for a finite topological space is just the set {$a$} with discrete topology. It seems like it works to me, but it's so stupid I thought something had to be wrong. Also, is this the only case for finite topological spaces? Because if #$X >1$, then #$X \times X >$ #$X$, so we can't establish a bijection. So if I wanted to find such a topological space without the discrete topology, can anyone think of such an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct: taking a one-point space (which carries exactly one topology!) works.

It is a little strange though that you speak of "finite topological spaces", since for a finite space your example works only if it has a single element (or, even more trivially, no elements at all).  In general if $X \times X \cong X$ then we need $\# X \cdot \# X  = \# X$.  For finite sets this is only true if the cardinality is $0$ or $1$, but assuming the Axiom of Choice it holds *for all infinite sets*.

**Added**: I read your question more carefully and what you are saying no longer seems strange: yes, as you say, your example and the empty set are the only ones among finite topological spaces.

Any infinite set $X$ endowed with the discrete topology gives an example.  For another example....take any infinite set endowed with the **indiscrete topology** $\tau_X = \{ \varnothing, X \}$.

There are more interesting examples.  For instance, if you start with *any* topological space $Y$ and put $X = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} Y$, then $X$ is such an example.  If you take $Y$ to be for instance the unit circle then you get an example with a compact Hausdorff space which is not discrete.

Comment: Thank you, I just have one follow up: I thought of your suggestion using the indiscrete topology on an infinite set (in particular, $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't see a bijection here either. If you used the natural map $f(x) = (x,x)$, the tuple $(1,0)$ has no preimage in $\mathbb{R}$ and I don't see how to get around this type of problem using a different choice of map

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but: it is easy to see that any product of indiscrete spaces is an indiscrete space.  Moreover, any two indiscrete spaces are homeormophic iff the underlying sets are in bijection.  It follows that if you endow e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology then $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you are asking why any infinite set $X$ is in bijection with $X \times X$, see e.g. Theorem 8 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/settheorypart2.pdf.

Comment: I get a 404 for that link